# How to create composite GSI PK in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have tried creating GSI with a PK that uses a composite value of **business_id, type_id, partner_id** fields. I did it in two different ways in the AWS console:

First: `business_id#type_id#partner_id`
Second: `[business_id]#[type_id]#[partner_id]`

and sort key: `updated`

Here is the query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM "items"."composite_key-index" 
 WHERE business_id = 435634652 AND type_id = 2 AND partner_id = 69992528
 ORDER BY updated ASC
```

In both cases it throws this error:

> ValidationException: Must have at least one non-optional hash key
> condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause.

And if I run it without the order by:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM "items"."composite_key-index" 
 WHERE business_id = 435634652 AND type_id = 2 AND partner_id = 69992528
```

it doesnt return any items, even though there are data matching those values.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

To use a composite value as a key, you have to build the values yourself.

Your application would have to store the value in a single attribute, ex GSI_PK, as `435634652#2#6992528`

Then your query would look like

```
SELECT *
 FROM "items"."composite_key-index" 
 WHERE GSI_PK = "435634652#2#6992528"
```

Comment: Store data in the same attribute? Oh so one attribute will contain all three different values (based on my example).

Comment: @showtime correct.

Comment: Is "composite_key-index" indexing GSI_PK attribute?

Comment: GSI_PK and either a new sort key or updated since you wanted it in ordered by updated.

Comment: I tried but when ordering by fails. Here I posted it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732144/why-querying-with-order-by-fails-in-dynamodb